# Strange suffix when converting String to NSURL

Tags: string, nsurl

I´m getting a strange suffix when converting a String to NSURL.

Here my code:

```
@IBAction func convert() {

    let pasteboardString = "http://www.jumbosoft.eu"
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pasteboardString)

}
```

the result of url is "http:/www.jumbosoft.eu -- ile:///" and I don´t understand where this suffix " -- ile:///" comes from.

Maybe somebody could try this action. Im using Xcode 7 and Xcode 7.1

Answer (score 1):

since the string is an internet address the conversion must be this way:

**let url = NSURL(string: pasteboardString)**

That did the trick.